# SharePoint 2013 REST API pass variabile to update list item function doesn't work

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to update a list item in Sharepoint 2013 with Ajax Jquery.
My function is the following one:

```
function update(item) {
var item = {
        __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.RisultatiAziendaliListItem" },
        event: $('#mainEvent').text(),
        user: $('#user').text(),
        day: Day,
        hour: Hour,
        unique: uniqueID
  };

$.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RisultatiAziendali')/items("+ user +")",
        method: "PATCH",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose;",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                       "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                       "If-Match": "*",
                       "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"                              
       },
       success: function (item) {
                  console.log('Item added successfully');
      },    
      error: function (error) {
           console.log("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
     }
  });
```

}

Unfourtenetly I receive the following error:

```
PATCH http://p-net/sites/sharedareas/fqt/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RisultatiAziendali')/items([object%20HTMLSpanElement]) 400 (Bad Request)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your support.

Comment: I am using documentation from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31995.sharepoint-2013-working-with-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax.aspx#Update_List_Item

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are seeing this error is because you are passing a variable (`user`) which is an object into the URL. It is expecting the ID of the item you intend on updating. It should be constructed as below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RisultatiAziendali')/items(**1**)
```